# List all available extensions using Python to get extension code

Tags: arcpy, extensions

I am building an extension which depends on the availability of another extension (not from Esri) so I'd like to find out if another extension is available using Python.

Based on the availability of this other extension, I want to set the 'Enable' property of toolbar icons.

I tried to use the `arcpy.CheckExtension('')` however I am getting this message
*`Unrecognized extension code'`. This is because I don't know the extension code.

Is there a way to list all the available or enabled extensions with their extension code?

**Edited:**
From the Customize > Extensions.. I can see the extension is enabled (checked) but from python I like to find if it is enabled/checked. I tried arcpy.CheckExtension('') with displayed named but no luck.

Comment: did you try to use `try import exception`

Comment: When you say "another extension (not from esri)" do you mean a Python AddIn extension written using ArcPy but not written by Esri, or something else?

Comment: @PlyGeo: The extension is written in ArcObjects.NET to my knowledge.I am not fully dependent on this external extension but I like to know whether it is installed and available/enabled.

Comment: @HugoRoussaffa-GeoDatup: Please see the comments below.

Answer (score 2):

To my knowledge there is no function in `arcpy` for return a list of Extensions. In the Help file under the syntax section for the [CheckExtension()](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-functions/checkoutextension.htm) method it actually lists all the codes so you can test them individually.

I don't believe `arcpy` can determine which extensions are turned on/off at the Application level (i.e. in ArcMap).Happy to be proven wrong! Also there is no mechanism for ticking them on/off. I think arcpy, which to me is primarily for scripting, interacts with extensions in a different way and exposes geo-processing tools from the geo-processing framework rather than enabling controls on the user interface in ArcMap\ArcCatalog.